# How can I fix a failing launcher icon after I moved my application?

Tags: 16.04, launcher, icons, .desktop

I am using pygame right now to learn about it. When i first executed the program file from terminal ; there was an icon of the program window. I locked it to launcher and it used to run my program; each time i clicked on it.

But when i changed the location of that python file; the icon was still there ( in the launcher)  and when i tried to make a new icon for my new program; the previous icon was coming and it was doing nothing on clicks.

Any ideas?

Comment: Remove the corresponding .desktop file from ~/.local/share/applications and repeat the routine, or edit the file to point to the new location.

Comment: @JacobVlijm  ThankYou so much.  :))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What happened?

If you launch a GUI application from the terminal, the possible corresponding `.desktop` file is looked up as the application's representative in the launcher.
The priority to look up then is:

1. `~/.local/share/applications`
2. `/usr/share/applications`

If in neither of these directories a valid representative is found, the application appears in the launcher with a generic icon. Right-clicking the icon and choosing <kbd>Lock to Launcher</kbd>, as you did, will then create a `.desktop` file in `[1]`.

This `.desktop` file includes the full command + path you ran the application with, in the`Exec=` -line.

#### How to fix if you moved the application?

Simply either:

- Delete the (`.desktop`) file from `~/.local/share/applications`, run your application again from cli and lock it again to the launcher.

or

- Open the representing `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications` with e.g. `gedit`

  ```
  gedit ~/.local/share/applications/<.desktop_file>
  ```

  and change the line, starting with `Exec=` to represent the application in the correct path.